# Query data in Azure DataBricks from Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have an Azure DataFactory instance and I want to query data from Azure Databricks. We have unity catlog in Databricks. What are my options here? Best practice?

I haven't really tried it technically, I want to get pointed into the right direction before trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add to @AnnuKumari answer,
that you can also use Databricks delta tables as a source without writing to a file first.
You can create a linked service in ADF to databricks:

[image: databricks linked service]

See this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-databricks-delta-lake?tabs=data-factory

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the Databricks Notebook activity in Azure Data Factory to run a Databricks notebook against the Databricks jobs cluster.
- The notebook can contain the code to extract data from the Databricks catalog and write it to a file or database. You can then use Azure Data Factory to copy the data from the file or database to your desired destination.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook#databricks-notebook-activity

[https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure-blog/azure-data-factory-and-azure-databricks-best-practices/ba-p/3074262#:~:text=ADF%20copy%20activities%20can%20ingest%20data%20from%20various,make%20sure%20to%20check%20out%20this%20blog%20post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/analytics-on-azure-blog/azure-data-factory-and-azure-databricks-best-practices/ba-p/3074262#:%7E:text=ADF%20copy%20activities%20can%20ingest%20data%20from%20various,make%20sure%20to%20check%20out%20this%20blog%20post).